# disable Infopath for new sites

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

We would like to turn InfoPath services completely off on our tenant, at least for newly created sites. I didn't find a central switch for this in the sharepoint admin center, is this possible or do I need to do this on every site after they are created? Can I change the Teams / Communication site templates to disable this feature by default?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to the below URL:

https://yourtenantsite-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TenantForms.FormServer.aspx

Example:
https://globalsharepoint2020-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/TenantForms.FormServer.aspx

By default, InfoPath service is disabled in the modern admin center:

[image: Infopath Service in modern admin center]

Once we click on the "**Allow**" checkbox, we will get the below message, so now this will be enabled.

[image: Enable Infopath Service in modern admin center]

Answer (score 0):

Configure InfoPath Forms Services for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/configure-infopath-forms-services